# Razor uses old name of custom class in model after refactoring

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have multiple projects in my website, the ones implied here are:

- `Common` : contains a class that I renamed using refactoring (say I renamed it from `OldName` to `NewName`)
- `ViewModels` : contains a ViewModel named `MyModel` which had a property of type `OldName` but now it's type is `NewName`
- Website : an asp.net mvc4 website with razor, where I try to display a textbox `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Town)`

When I have done the refactoring, eveything was right, the type in my model changed and went from `public OldName Town { get; set; }` to `public NewName Town { get; set; }`

But when I run my application and it tries to execute the razor template in which `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Town)` is implemented it keeps throwing an exception saying `There is no type 'OldName' in the model`...

I tried deleting the temporary asp.net files, deleting the bin/debug folder, changing the razor template involved, rebuilding the solution, stoping the server and trying all that again, nothing worked, I still got the same error.

Didn't find anything about that on google too... (but perhaps I didn't type the right keywords).

Does anyone have an idea about how I could solve this problem?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have to change both the `model` type in your EditorTemplate to be `NewName` and the actual filename of the EditorTemplate to `NewName.cshtml`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! How didn't I see that.... Actually I also had to rename the `@model Common.OldName` to `@model Common.NewName` in several files, seems that refactoring doesn't change that. Anyway your answer solved the problem, thanks again

Comment: @ppetrov No problems! You see ReSharper immediately throws an error if you forget to do that in views. One of the many great reasons I love it.

Comment: Heard of, but never used it, but if it shows that kind of things I may give it a try!